# Python: selecting a section of an image

Tags: python, opencv, keras, computer-vision

I want to select any one of the below data matrix from the image. I have to perform this operation on several images, though the image layout is exactly the same for the images, owing to how the pic is taken the position of the data matrix might change from the image edges.

Input Image:
[image]

Expected Output.

[image]

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What did you try up to now?

Answer (score 0):

considering the cam position same for other images and the same image size I guess It helps you

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("scan.jpg")
h,w = img.shape[0:2]
print(h,w)
img = cv2.resize(img,(640,512))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > 1000 and area<2000:
         x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
         cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
         mat = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
         cv2.imwrite("mat.png",mat)
         #cv2.imshow("mat",mat)


cv2.imshow("thresh",ing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: output matrix]